# sed: delete all lines before matching one, including this one

Tags: sed, files, text, delete, line

**TARGET**

How to delete all lines in a text file before a matching one, including this one?

Input file example:

```
apple
pear
banana
HI_THERE
lemon
coconut
orange
```

Desired output:

```
lemon
coconut
orange
```

The aim is to do it in sed to use the "-i" option (direct editing).

**CLEAN SOLUTION ?**

Most answers for similar problems propose something like:

```
sed -n '/HI_THERE/,$p' input_file
```

But the matched line is not deleted:

```
HI_THERE
lemon
coconut
orange
```

Then, knowing this will delete all from matched line (including it) to end of file:

```
sed '/HI_THERE/,$d' input_file
```

I tried something like this:

```
sed '^,/HI_THERE/d' input_file
```

But then sed complains:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `^'
```

**DIRTY SOLUTION**

The last (dirty) solution is using pipeline:

```
sed -n '/HI_THERE/,$p' input_file | tail -n +2
```

but then, direct edit of the file doesn't work:

```
sed -n '/HI_THERE/,$p' input_file | tail -n +2 > input_file
cat input_file # returns nothing
```

and one must use a temporary file like that...

```
sed -n '/HI_THERE/,$p' input_file | tail -n +2 > tmp_file
mv tmp_file input_file
```

Comment: I think you wanted `1`, not `^`. Does that work for you?

Comment: Ach.... it works :) (please, publish this as an answer so that I can validate it :-) )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to your "clean solution":

```
sed -e '1,/HI_THERE/d' input_file
```

The first line in the file is line 1 - there's no special `^` address because you always know that, while `$` is needed for the end because you don't (necessarily) know which line that is.

This does fall over if the matching line is the *first* line of the file. With GNU sed you can use `0` instead of `1` to deal with that. For POSIX sed and for portability (which seem to be different in this case) it's more complex (see comments below and [this follow-up question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/534675/73093)).

Comment: IIRC this will fail to match (hence deleting to the end of the file) if `HI_THERE` occurs *in* line 1 (in GNU sed, one can use `0,/HI_THERE/` to cover this special case)

Comment: POSIX-compatibly you can use `sed -e '1{/HI_THERE/d;};1,//d'` if that is an issue.

Comment: @MichaelHomer This POSIX version will not help, I'm afraid. All lines will get killed by the `1,//d` anyhow.

Comment: @Philippos Will they? Not on any system I can find, and the specified meaning of `d` is "delete and start the next cycle", so I can't see how `1,//d` ever even runs if the first line matches.

Comment: I have found a theoretically-POSIX-compatible version in Solaris 10 that doesn't work *at all* on that command, though, so investigating that...

Comment: @MichaelHomer Yes, it does, I just veryfied it with GNU `sed`, no output. After deleting the first line, second cycle it started, finds itself in the range between first line and pattern and deletes.

Comment: `sed '/HI_THERE/,$!d;//d'` would be a valid POSIX solution

Comment: Interesting. I read that as a conformance bug, but the "Addresses" section is a little ambiguous. It's not what BSD nor SunOS xpg4 sed does. That may be a specification issue to be raised.

Comment: I'm still not sure which is wrong, but as a minimal case `printf 'a\nb\n'|sed -e '1{d;};1,/a/p'` behaves how I expect on BSD/macOS sed and Solaris' POSIX sed (one output line), and not on GNU sed (two output lines), including in its POSIX mode. Busybox matches GNU sed. I will try to have a prod at more exotic systems. There is an argument for either interpretation of the specification text and I'm no longer certain which one I expect from it. Presumably Solaris and macOS have passed the conformance suites, though, so that ought to be correct. Thanks for the comments! I've just edited yours in.

Comment: I suggest to start a question of its own out of this finding

Comment: A `sed -e '1,/HI/d' file` fails if the first line match the regex. A `sed -e '1{/HI/d;};1,//d' file` will remove up to the **second** regex match or the whole file if no second match exists. A `sed '/HI/,$!d;//d' file` will remove **all** lines where the regex match.

Comment: @Philippos I [have posted a question about this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/534675/73093). It comes up with something as simple as `1d;1,2d` with the same divergence of behaviour between implementations.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up, @MichaelHomer !

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick to Posix sed you could use this:

```
sed -ne '
  /HI_THERE/!d
  :loop
    n
    p
  bloop
' inp.file
```

Or, written in a condensed manner:

```
sed -n '/HI_THERE/!d;:a;n;p;ba' inp.file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -ne 'print if 1 <(/HI_THERE/...eof)' input_file
```

Where we make use of the range operator `...` to form the proper range and further constrain it to reject the first element within the selected range.

Answer (score 0):

## sed

There is no simple way in sed to do what you ask for.
The simplest portable POSIXly solution for sed is something like:

```
sed -ne '/HI/{:1' -e 'n;p;b1' -e '}'
```

Other simple solutions are:

```
sed '0,/HI/d'      ./file             # GNU sed
awk 'f; /HI/{f=1}' ./file
```

---

## ed

The closest POSIXly non-sed solution is with `ed`. Just remove the range from the first line of the file to the regex `/HI/`, even if `HI` is on the same first line.

```
printf '%s\n' 1,/HI/d ,p Q | ed -s file
```

Or

```
ed -Gs imfile2 <<-\edscript
1,/HI/d
,p
Q
edscript
```

Which means:

- printing no additional information (number of lines read) with option `-s`
- remove (delete) all lines from the first line of the `file` to the regex `/HI/` (`1,/HI/d`).
- then print the whole file (`,p`).
- and exit even if the file has been modified (`Q`).

If you want to modify the file replace `,p Q` with just `w` (write to file).

## Why `sed` fails on 1,/HI/d while `ed` works ?

Because `sed` expects the regex to match on the next line.

In `ed`, either `3,3` `3,/3/` `/3/,3` `/3/,/3/` will print only one 3:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 3,3p   3,/3/p   /3/3p   /3/,/3/p   Q | ed -s <(seq 5)
3
3
3
3
```

While sed will do this:

```
$ sed -ne 3,3p  <(seq 5)
3

$ sed -ne 3,/3/p  <(seq 5)
3
4
5

$ sed -ne /3/,3p  <(seq 5)
3

$ sed -ne /3/,/3/p <(seq 5)
3
4
5
```

A regex at the end of a range is expected to match a line **following** the line matched on the start of the range (the left of the `,`). There is no `3` following line numbered `3`, so sed prints all following lines (`4` and `5`).

That is why GNU sed solves the issue with `0,/HI/`.

## Why `:1;n;p;b1` ?

A way to print all lines (except the first) of a range is to use a loop that **first** asks for the next line and **then** prints it:

```
$     sed -n '5{:1;n;p;b1}' <(seq 8)    # GNU syntax
6
7
8
```

So, simply match the regex you need `/HI/` and get inside such loop.

```
sed -n '/HI/{:1;n;p;b1}' file        # GNU syntax
```

Which needs to be expanded to a more complex script because some older seds don't allow `labels` to be finished by the `;`.

```
sed -n -e '/HI/{:1' -e 'n;p;b1' -e '}' file        # portable syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

`grep -nw HI_THERE file.txt |awk -F":" '{print $1}' | xargs -I % sed '1,%d' file.txt`

Explanation: I grep using exact word `w`, get the line number `n`
Next, I pull the line number using awk, the separator is `:`
Further I pipe this using xargs and delete until then.

Answer (score -1):

sed is for doing s/old/new on individual strings that is all. For anything else you should use awk, e.g. with any awk in any shell on every UNIX box and handling "HI_THERE" appearing on any line:

```
$ awk 'f; /HI_THERE/{f=1}' file
lemon
coconut
orange
```

If you want GNU sed for `-i` then use GNU awk for `-i inplace` instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17914105/1745001 for other scripts to select sections of files.

Comment: Hi, Ed, why not better `<file` instead of `file` for really odd named files?

Comment: @Isaac Because `<file` strips you of the ability to access `FILENAME` and isn't extensible to use with multiple input files which is a very common situation when using awk. If your file names contain odd characters just quote them appropriately in either case and it makes no difference which approach you use in the call to awk. The only mild benefit to using `<file` is in the error case - if `file` doesn't exist or can't be read then if you write `awk '1' foo > bar` then `bar` is created while with `awk '1' <foo > bar` it isn't and you get an error message from the shell instead of from awk.

Comment: That makes sense. However, if a file is named `var=value file`, awk will set a variable inside awk in either `awk '...' "var=value file"` or in `awk '...' 'var=value file'` even in `awk '...' "$file"` or the *should be avoided in any case* `awk '...' $file`. How to quote that?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's just the well-documented `awk 'script' './var=value file'`

Comment: Simple solution !. Got it, thanks Ed.

Comment: @Isaac Hmm, I may have been too quick to say "well-documented". I thought it was but I just googled and looked through the POSIX spec and the gawk manual and couldn't find it so I emailed the gawk maintainers and asked them to add it to the next revision of the manual.