# What does POSIX sed require for `1d;1,2d` where an address range starts from an already-deleted line?

Tags: sed, posix

In the comments to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/533512/73093) a case came up where various sed implementations disagreed on a fairly simple program, and we (or at least I) weren't able to determine what the specification actually requires for it.

The issue is the behaviour of a range beginning at a deleted line:

```
1d;1,2d
```

**Should line 2 be deleted** even though the start of the range was removed before reaching that command? My initial expectation was "no" in line with BSD sed, while GNU sed says "yes", and checking the specification text doesn't entirely resolve the matter.

Matching my expectation are (at least) macOS and Solaris `sed`, and BSD `sed`. Disagreeing are (at least) GNU and Busybox `sed`, and numerous people here. The first two are SUS-certified while the others are likely more widespread. **Which behaviour is correct?**

---

The [specification text](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) for two-address ranges says:

> The *sed* utility shall then apply in sequence all commands whose addresses select that pattern space, until a command starts the next cycle or quits.

and

> An editing command with two addresses shall select the inclusive range from the first pattern space that matches the first address through the next pattern space that matches the second. [...] Starting at the first line following the selected range, sed shall look again for the first address. Thereafter, the process shall be repeated.

Arguably, line 2 **is** *within* "the inclusive range from the first pattern space that matches the first address through the next pattern space that matches the second", regardless of whether the start point has been deleted. On the other hand, I expected the first `d` to move on to the next cycle and not give the range a chance to start. The UNIX™-certified implementations do what I expected, but potentially not what the specification mandates.

Some illustrative experiments follow, but the key question is: **what *should* `sed` do when a range begins on a deleted line?**

---

## Experiments and examples

A simplified demonstration of the issue is this, which prints extra copies of lines rather than deleting them:

```
printf 'a\nb\n' | sed -e '1d;1,2p'
```

This provides `sed` with two lines of input, `a` and `b`. The program does two things:

1. Deletes the first line with `1d`. The `d` command [will](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html)

   > Delete the pattern space and start the next cycle.
   >   and
2. Select the range of lines from 1 to 2 and explicitly prints them out, in addition to the automatic printing every line receives. A line included in the range should thus appear twice.

My expectation was that this should print

```
b
```

only, with the range not applying because `1,2` is never reached during line 1 (because `d` jumped to the next cycle/line already) and so range inclusion never begins, while `a` has been deleted. The conformant Unix `sed`s of macOS and Solaris 10 produce this output, as does the non-POSIX `sed` in Solaris and BSD `sed` in general.

GNU sed, on the other hand, prints

```
b
b
```

indicating that it *has* interpreted the range. This occurs both in POSIX mode and not. Busybox's sed has the same behaviour (but not identical behaviour always, so it doesn't seem to be a result of shared code).

Further experimentation with

```
printf 'a\nb\nc\nd\ne\n' | sed -e '2d;2,/c/p'
printf 'a\nb\nc\nd\ne\n' | sed -e '2d;2,/d/p'
```

finds that it appears to treat a range starting at a deleted line as though it starts on the *following* line. This is visible because `/c/` does not match to end the range. Using `/b/` to start the range does *not* behave the same as `2`.

---

The initial working example I was using was

```
printf '%s\n' a b c d e | sed -e '1{/a/d;};1,//d'
```

as a way to delete all lines up to the first `/a/` match, even if that is on the first line (what GNU sed would use `0,/a/d` for — this was an attempted POSIX-compatible rendition of that).

It has been suggested that this should instead delete up to the *second* match of `/a/` if the first line matches (or the whole file if there's no second match), which seems plausible - but again, only GNU sed does that. Both macOS sed and Solaris's sed produce

```
b
c
d
e
```

for that, as I expected (GNU sed produces the empty output from removing the unterminated range; Busybox sed prints just `d` and `e`, which is clearly wrong no matter what). Generally I'd assume that their having passed the certification conformance tests means that their behaviour is correct, but enough people have suggested otherwise that I'm not sure, the specification text isn't completely convincing, and the test suite can't be perfectly comprehensive.

Clearly it isn't practically portable to write that code today given the inconsistency, but *theoretically* it should be equivalent everywhere with one meaning or the other. I think this is a bug, but I don't know against which implementation(s) to report it. My view currently is that GNU and Busybox sed's behaviour is inconsistent with the specification, but I could be mistaken on that.

What does POSIX require here?

Comment: As a temporary workaround, write to a temp file and process it with POSIX `ed`, bypassing `sed` altogether?

Answer (score 9):

That was raised on the Austin group mailing list in March 2012. Here's the final message on that (by Geoff Clare of the Austin Group (the body that maintains POSIX), who is also the one who raised the issue in the first place). Here copied from the gmane NNTP interface:

> ```
> Date: Fri, 16 Mar 2012 17:09:42 +0000
> From: Geoff Clare <gwc-7882/jkIBncuagvECLh61g@public.gmane.org>
> To: austin-group-l-7882/jkIBncuagvECLh61g@public.gmane.org
> Newsgroups: gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general
> Subject: Re: Strange addressing issue in sed
>
> Stephane Chazelas <stephane_chazelas-Qt13gs6zZMY@public.gmane.org> wrote, on 16 Mar 2012:
> >
> > 2012-03-16 15:44:35 +0000, Geoff Clare:
> > > I've been alerted to an odd behaviour of sed on certified UNIX
> > > systems that doesn't seem to match the requirements of the
> > > standard.  It concerns an interaction between the 'n' command
> > > and address matching.
> > > 
> > > According to the standard, this command:
> > > 
> > > printf 'A\nB\nC\nD\n' | sed '1,3s/A/B/;1,3n;1,3s/B/C/'
> > > 
> > > should produce the output:
> > > 
> > > B
> > > C
> > > C
> > > D
> > > 
> > > GNU sed does produce this, but certified UNIX systems produce this:
> > > 
> > > B
> > > B
> > > C
> > > D
> > > 
> > > However, if I change the 1,3s/B/C/ to 2,3s/B/C/ then they produce
> > > the expected output (tested on Solaris and HP-UX).
> > > 
> > > Is this just an obscure bug from common ancestor code, or is there
> > > some legitimate reason why this address change alters the behaviour?
> > [...]
> > 
> > I suppose the idea is that for the second 1,3cmd, line "1" has
> > not been seen, so the 1,3 range is not entered.
>
> Ah yes, now it makes sense, and it looks like the standard does
> require this slightly strange behaviour, given how the processing
> of the "two addresses" case is specified:
>
>     An editing command with two addresses shall select the inclusive
>     range from the first pattern space that matches the first address
>     through the next pattern space that matches the second.  (If the
>     second address is a number less than or equal to the line number
>     first selected, only one line shall be selected.) Starting at the
>     first line following the selected range, sed shall look again for
>     the first address. Thereafter, the process shall be repeated.
>
> It's specified this way because the addresses can be BREs, but if
> the same matching process is applied to the line numbers (even though
> they can only match at most once), then the 1,3 range on that last
> command is never entered.
>
> -- 
> Geoff Clare <g.clare-7882/jkIBncuagvECLh61g@public.gmane.org>
> The Open Group, Apex Plaza, Forbury Road, Reading, RG1 1AX, England
> ```

And here's the relevant part of the rest of the message (by me) that Geoff was quoting:

> ```
> I suppose the idea is that for the second 1,3cmd, line "1" has
> not been seen, so the 1,3 range is not entered.
>
> Same idea as in
>
> printf '%s\n' A B C | sed -n '1d;1,2p'
>
> whose behavior differ in traditional (heirloom toolchest at
> least) and GNU.
>
> It's unclear to me whether POSIX wants one behavior or the
> other.
> ```

So, (according to Geoff) POSIX is *clear* that the GNU behaviour is non-compliant.

And it's true it's less consistent (compare `seq 10 | sed -n '1d;1,2p'` with `seq 10 | sed -n '1d;/^1$/,2p'`) even if potentially less surprising to people who don't realise how ranges are processed (even Geoff initially found the conforming behaviour *"strange"*).

Nobody bothered reporting it as a bug to the GNU folks. I'm not sure I'd qualify it as a bug. Probably the best option would be for the POSIX specification to be updated to allow both behaviours to make it clear that one cannot rely on either.

**Edit**. I've now had a look at the original `sed` implementation in Unix V7 from the late 70s, and it looks pretty much like that behaviour for numeric addresses was not intended or at least not thought through completely there.

With Geoff's reading of the spec (and my original interpretation of why it happens), conversely, in:

```
seq 5 | sed -n '3d;1,3p'
```

lines 1, 2, 4 and 5 should be output, because this time, it's the end address that is never encountered by the `1,3p` ranged command, like in `seq 5 | sed -n '3d;/1/,/3/p'`

Yet, that doesn't happen in the original implementation, nor any other implementation I tried (busybox `sed` returns lines 1, 2 and 4 which looks more like a bug).

If you look at [the UNIX v7 code](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7/usr/src/cmd/sed/sed1.c#L82), it does check for the case where the current line number is *greater* than the (numerical) end address, and gets out of the range then. The fact that [it doesn't do it for the start address](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7/usr/src/cmd/sed/sed1.c#L105) looks more like an oversight then than an intentional design.

What that means is that there's no implementation that is actually compliant to that interpretation of the POSIX spec in that regard at the moment.

Another confusing behaviour with the GNU implementation is:

```
$ seq 5 | sed -n '2d;2,/3/p'
3
4
5
```

Since line 2 was skipped, the `2,/3/` is entered upon line 3 (the first line whose number is >= 2). But as it's the line that made us *enter* the range, it's not checked for the *end* address. It gets worse with `busybox sed` in:

```
$ seq 10 | busybox sed -n '2,7d; 2,3p'
8
```

Since lines 2 to 7 were deleted, line 8 is the first one that is >= 2 so the 2,3 range is *entered* then!

Comment: So it sounds like the issue is still unresolved — I agree with your reasoning for why it's happening, but also that it's unclear whether that was what was wanted  — though it does also sound like Geoff was convinced by the quoted text that the UNIX™ implementations were correct. Is that your reading as well?

Comment: @MichaelHomer, the idea is that (according to Geoff) POSIX is _clear_ that the GNU behaviour is non-compliant. And it's true it's less consistent (compare `seq 10 | sed -n '1d;1,2p'` with `seq 10 | sed -n '1d;/^1$/,2p'`) even if potentially less surprising to people would don't realise how ranges are processed. Nobody bothered reporting it as a bug to the GNU folks. I'm not sure I'd qualify it as a bug, probably the best option would be to update the POSIX spec to allow both behaviours to make it clear that one can not rely on either.

Comment: Actually, as the POSIX definition makes no statement that addresses need to be "seen" to start or end an address range, IMO the GNU implementation follows the POSIX wording more strictly (surprising for GNU!). This is also desired behaviour for most real-world cases I  know. But, as you point out, it would need to be consistent. And checking each line for range patterns even after `d` is not only a performance issue, it leads to further implementation issues as "unseen" patterns needed for ranges are not allowed to have effect on further empty patterns ... a mess!

Comment: @Philippos, in that `1d;1,2p` script the `1,2p` command is not run on the first line, so the _first address_ is not matched by _any pattern space_, which is one way to interpret that text. In any case, it should be obvious that the evaluation of addresses should be made at the time the command is run. Like in `sed 's/./x/g; /xxx/,/xxx/d'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I understand this way to look at it, but the "line 2 stays in the `1,3` range, no matter when it has been tested" view is reasonable, too. As explained, the consistency argument is the one that convinces me against the GNU implementation.

Comment: What do you expect that `seq 10 | sed -n '1d;5p'` should print?

Comment: @Isaac, well `5`, but there's no range in there.

Comment: Oh, sure there is no range there. but what was printed (5) was counting from line 1 (already erased). If erased meant that lines should be renumbered, a 6 should have been printed. Agreed?

Comment: @Isaac, it's not what it's about. The current line number is increased any time a new line of input is read in, there's no ambiguity in that. The problem in `1d;1,2p` is that the `1,2p` command is not run when the current line number is 1 (because `d` is run and d stops processing at that point), so the 1,2 range is never _entered_ (in POSIX compliant sed implementations). That would be the same in `1d;1,9p`.

Comment: But when re-entering the script in line 2, the range `1,2` should match, should it not?

Comment: @Isaac, not if you consider that that `1,2` range has never seen _line 1_. It may become clearer if you replace it with `1d;/^1$/,/^2$/` for example. The line `1` did match that `/^1$/` address, but since it was deleted, the `/^1$/,/^2$/` range never saw it, so the range was never entered.

Comment: Having said that, by that same reading, I would expect `seq 5 | sed -n '3d;1,3p'` to  output lines 1, 2, 4, 5 like `sed -n '3d;/1/,/3/p'` since the *end* address is never found, but no implementation does AFAICT.

Comment: In `seq 5 | sed -n '3d;1,3p'` the line at **position** 3 was deleted, so it prints **nothing**. The range gets matched. If not, it should continue to the end of the input.Exactly as `seq 5 | sed -n '3d;1,5p'` doesn't print a `3`. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: The fact that a line is deleted (actually emptied, made NUL) doesn't mean it doesn't exist. Line at position 1 always exists for a non-empty file. It should be matched by the address `1` in any case. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: In `sed -n '3d;/1/,/3/p'` you are matching the **contents** of the line, not its address. A line with a `3` is never found, thus sed keeps searching for a number 3 (and thus printing).@StéphaneChazelas

Comment: @Isaac, that's the core of the issue. In the POSIX language `1` and `/1/` are both addresses, `1` is the address when the line number is 1, `/1/` is the address when the pattern space contains `1`, the question is whether both types of address should be  treated the same, or if line number ranges should considered "in the absolute" regardless of whether they did match. See also my latest edit for more historical context.

Comment: So, Is your claim that in `/.{3}/,6` the `.{3}` is an address?

Comment: @Isaac, check [the specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/sed.html)